# Is takeback legal in OTB chess?

Tags: otb-chess

It is normal for an experienced player to allow his low rated opponent a takeback in casual chess. Does this apply for FIDE rated OTB tournaments, **provided both players agree**?

Comment: Not legal, but considering that most rules enforcement begins with a player making a claim, if both players agreed I guess they could get away with a takeback. The real question is, why would anyone want to agree to a takeback in a rated tournament? :-)

Comment: Sometimes your opponent blunders, and you think they played a killer move, while they know they blundered. In this case, you will allow them a takeback :)